# Printing Pi with Array - decimal point

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I been trying to get this program to print a decimal point but i dont now how to go about it, ive tried various if else statements and need guidance on what to do !! ive commented the part im stuck on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 10

int main(void) {
    
    int pi[MAX_DIGITS] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3};
    printf("How many digits of pi would you like to print? ");
    int numDigits;
    scanf("%d", &numDigits);
    
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numDigits) {
    //if user enters 1 digit  
        if (numDigits == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", pi[0]);
        } else if (numDigits > 1) { // for > 1 digit, include decimal point 
      
  /* incorrect -> 
   
       printf("%d.", pi[0]);
        printf("%d", [pi[i+1]);
        }      
 */
        i++;    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just do pi[i]. Also your program will crash if numDigits is greater than 10, since MAX_DIGITS is 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS 10

int main(void) {
    
    int pi[MAX_DIGITS] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3};
    printf("How many digits of pi would you like to print? ");
    int numDigits;
    scanf("%d", &numDigits);
    
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numDigits && i < MAX_DIGITS) {
        printf("%d", pi[i]);
        if(i==0 && numDigits > 1)
            printf(".");
        i++;    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be safe, I would initialize numDigits to 0; And also have the while(i < numDigits && numDigits < MAX_DIGITS)

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Initializing `numDigits` is unnecessary.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, unncessary, but good habit. Will keep you in the habit for future more complex cases, where we should be initializing stuff to nullptr, etc. Especially if someone comes along and starts moving declarations around on different lines, and something bad happens by accessing it

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I would advice AGAINST unnecessary initializations. If you're reading a variable before you have initialized it properly, you'll get a warning. Initializing with dummy values "just to be safe" will hide this warning.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI -- initializing code to sensible values is good practice; initializing code for its own sake is a bit of a code smell. Much more important here is that code is failing to check the value returned by `scanf()`; this mistake should never pass a code review.

Comment: The exception is possibly pointers. It' may be good to init them to NULL, since NULL basically means "uninitialized". But even here I'm not sure.